# Scrape many table using google app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets

I would love to scape data from this website: http://www.tunisieindustrie.nat.tn/fr/dbi.asp?action=result&ident=1

I want to scrape the whole table. I tried using this :

````
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('A3');
  range.clear();
  range.setFormula('=IF(row(4:4)-2>$C$2;"";(transpose(QUERY(IMPORTHTML(CONCAT("http://www.tunisieindustrie.nat.tn/fr/dbi.asp?action=result&ident=";row(4:4)-2);"table";1);"select Col2";1))))');
 
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  /*var last =sheetName.getRange('C1').getValue(); ilsemblerait que ceci relance la requête*/
 
 spreadsheet.getRange('A3').activate();
 spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('A3:A5100'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
 spreadsheet.getRange('A3:A5100').activate();
}```
````

Comment: Have you tried UrlFetchApp?

Comment: Use of [setFormulasR1C1(formulas)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasr1c1formulas) would make you code simpler and more efficient.

Comment: @Tonnelier Tell me how I can do ?